# Error writing output file when I decryption files using openssl

Tags: openssl

I am working on an encrypted data set. And using the code below to decrypt files.

```
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -d -in $encryptedfile -out $decrypted_file -pass file:secret.txt
```

But I am always notified with this error:

```
error writing output file
```

Comment: are you sure you have write privileges for the output directory ?

Comment: What is the output if you run this with `strace`? It should show the error.

Comment: Don't use `openssl`. It's very hard to use correctly, it's just a debugging tool. The robust way to encrypt a file is with `gpg`.

Comment: @MelBurslan It might be yes. Because I find a new file is created, but nothing in that file.

Comment: @Gilles Can you give an example for my case? I tried "gpg -d $encryptedfile" but got error messages. BTW, my encrypted file name is ".aes"

Comment: @Wedoso Gpg won't decrypt files produced by openssl, only openssl can. I'm not saying you should use gpg for decryption, I'm saying you should use gpg for both encryption and decryption.

Comment: @Gilles Thanks. But I only get the key and encrypted files from the provider.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I don't have enough space to write decrypted files. But of course, we need to get the writing permission before using openssl to decrypt files.